# Recognising an input() as either a str, float, or int and acting accordingly

Tags: python, python-3.x

Python beginner here. I'm writing a program that uses an infinite loop and allows the user to enter key terms to access different 'tools' or 'modules'.

Within one of these 'modules', the user can enter a value and convert it to binary. I want to:

1. Allow the program to recognize if the value is either an int or a
   float and then run code that converts the value to binary
2. Allow the program to recognize if the value entered is a str and the str says 'back', in which the current loop will be exited.

As far as I know this issue is occurring as input() converts whatever is entered to a str automatically (due to: http://anh.cs.luc.edu/python/hands-on/3.1/handsonHtml/io.html "First it prints the string you give as a parameter").

How can I make the code below recognize if the input is a str, float, or int and then execute the relevant if statements? Currently, this part of my code can accept 'back' to exit out of the loop but will take any int or float value as a str, making the program prompt the user to enter a decimal value once more.

```
    #decimal to binary   
    while search == "d2b":
        dec2bin = input("\nDecimal Value: ")
        if type(dec2bin) == int:
            print("Binary Value: " + "{0:b}".format(dec2bin))
        elif type (dec2bin) == str:
            if dec2bin == "back":
                search = 0
        elif type (dec2bin) == float:
                #code for float to binary goes here
```

Edit: not the same as this thread ([Python: Analyzing input to see if its an integer, float, or string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22214313/python-analyzing-input-to-see-if-its-an-integer-float-or-string)), as a list is used there over input()
E2: cannot seem to use suggested duplicate as a solution to issue. However, a comment in this thread by Francisco has the solution

Comment: The question tagged as duplicate wasn't really. That was how to find the type of objects in a list -- not the type that a string could be converted into.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use exceptions! The `int` and `float` functions throw a `ValueError` exception when they can't convert the value passed.

```
while search == "d2b":
    dec2bin = input("\nDecimal Value: ")
    try:
        dec2bin = int(dec2bin)
    except ValueError:
        pass
    else:
        print("Binary Value: " + "{0:b}".format(dec2bin))
        continue

    try:
        dec2bin = float(dec2bin)
    except ValueError:
        pass
    else:
        #code for float to binary goes here
        continue

    if dec2bin == "back":
        search = 0
```

The order in which you try the conversions is important, since every value passed to `int` is valid with `float`, and every value passed to `float` is a valid to be passed to `str`

Comment: This seems to work correctly in my code, thanks. If you don't mind- can floats be formatted to binary in similar ways to how ints can? I'm doing some experimenting now with what I know about formatting and getting errors.

Comment: @CharlieWebb Depends on what you mean by converting a `float` to binary, maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16444726/binary-representation-of-float-in-python-bits-not-hex) answers your question.

Comment: So currently the code formats ints into binary as per:

 dec2bin = input("\nDecimal Value: ")
    try:
        dec2bin = int(dec2bin)
    except ValueError:
        pass
    else:
        print("Binary Value: " + "{0:b}".format(dec2bin))
        continue

Is something similar possible at the end of the float section of the code? Will I need to convert the float to a str or int? In terms of my own python knowledge reading that thread you linked is a bit of a no go at the moment- I don't understand most of the code in the replies.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`str.isalpha()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalpha) and [`str.isdigit()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit) to achieve this. Hence your code will be as:

```
while search == "d2b":
    dec2bin = input("\nDecimal Value: ")
    if dec2bin.lstrip("-").isdigit():
        print("Binary Value: " + "{0:b}".format(int(dec2bin))) # OR, simply bin(int(dec2bin))
    elif dec2bin.isalpha():  # OR, isalnum() based on the requirement
        if dec2bin == "back":
            search = 0
    else:
        try:
            _ = float(dec2bin)
        except:
            pass
        else:
            #code for float to binary goes here
```

Here, I am using [`str.lstrip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.lstrip) to remove `-` from the start of the string as `.isdigit()` can not check for *negative number string.*

Refer [Python 3: String Methods](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods) for complete list of methods available with `str` objects.

Comment: You can have a negative number

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: Updated the answer. Thanks for bringing it to notice.

Comment: I am out of votes so cannot +1, also you might want to look at what isdecimal does ;)

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: I would have. But the machine I am using right now is not having Python 3 installed. Please feel free to edit the answer if I did something wrong.

Comment: Lets just say `"3.4".isdecimal() -> False`, *Return true if all characters in the string are decimal characters* http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Nd/index.htm

Comment: `.decimal()` was not available with `Python 2.7`. Just checked the doc. I believe `x.isnumeric() and not x.isdigit()` should do the trick. again could not verify as `isnumeric` is also not present with 2.7

Comment: None of those work with floats. Unless the strings are all numbers they would all return false, the only difference is what they consider digits

Comment: OK. I am on my another machine now. You are right. Updated the answer with *traditional* `try/except`

Answer (score 0):

using `ast.literal_eval()` you can do a similar operation. here is a sample code of converting `input()` `str` to  `str`, `float`, and `int`.

```
import ast  
def input_conv(strr):
   try:
      base = ast.literal_eval(strr)
      return base
   except:
      return strr

>>> b = input()
hi
>>> input_conv(b)
'hi'
>>> type(input_conv(b))
<class 'str'>
>>> b = input()
1
>>> type(input_conv(b))
<class 'int'>
>>> b = input()
1.222
>>> type(input_conv(b))
<class 'float'>
```